# IDEA equivalent of Eclipse "type hierarchy" (F4)?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, you can select a Java class and show the class hierarchy ("open type hierarchy" or <kbd>F4</kbd> in default bindings). It opens the "Type Hierarchy" view, which lists its base classes and the tree of its subclasses.

I'm sure there is an equivalent in IDEA to get this information but I haven't found it yet.

**What workflow is best in IDEA to quickly show the base classes of a given class?**

Visualizing the subclasses is nice to have but less critical for me. In the editor, I can find the immediate subclasses easily via the "has subclasses" button on the left pane.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Is this the feature you are looking for? The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-structure-and-hierarchy-of-the-source-code.html

<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+U</kbd> also shows a type hierarchy: [How to show all parents and subclasses of a class in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990781/how-to-show-all-parents-and-subclasses-of-a-class-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. And you won the race by a few seconds. :-)

Comment: Why this menu item is not listed by right clicking the class name is sooooo beyond me... :(

Answer (score 12):

Try use Ctrl+H Hierarchy class panel should show.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to set the `Keymap` to `Eclipse` in IDE Settings and you would continue to be able to use `F4`. Go to Settings using `Ctrl+Alt+S` type Keymap in search box and change Keymaps to `Eclipse`.

Note: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.1 ultimate.

[image]