# What is the intellij shortcut for the shortcut Cmd + T on eclipse Mac?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on eclipse, that displays implementation classes and supertypes in a quick view window. I am not able to replicate it on Intellij. Is there a way I can replicate it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Eclipse's Ctrl+T shortcut equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990781/what-is-eclipses-ctrlt-shortcut-equivalent-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Try with  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>U</kbd> . Have a look at this [Similar for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990781/what-is-eclipses-ctrlt-shortcut-equivalent-in-intellij-idea)