# IntelliJ IDEA: Is there a way to list all interfaces implemented by a class and its parents?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface, superclass, class-hierarchy

I work on a relatively complex Java project where classes commonly have four or five ancestors before `Object`. Given such a class, e.g. `D` in a hierarchy like this: `Object > A > B > C > D`, I would like to know what all interfaces it effectively implements. That is, I am also interested in seeing that `D` implements, say, `Serializable` even if that is declared only in the declaration of class `B` and even when `D` does not actually implement any of the methods specified by the interface (naturally, if talking about `Serializable`).

Some potential sources of this information I tried include:

- using "Group by Defining Type" in the Structure window -- but that won't show empty interfaces (= interfaces without methods), and
- the "Hierarchy" window -- but that does not include interfaces when viewing the hierarchy for a class.

Is there a way to obtain this information in IDEA without having to open files of all ancestor classes of the class in question?

Comment: Not sure about the InteliJ but you can do it in a one line of code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616055/get-all-derived-interfaces-of-a-class

Comment: see also the almost duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990781/how-to-show-all-parents-and-subclasses-of-a-class-in-intellij-idea/9990283

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try

- Open the class file.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. (or just navigate through project window and press the keys.)
- You can see the ***Hierarchy Diagram*** appears right hand side.
- Try switch to ***Supertypes Hierarchy***(circled in red in below image) button. :))

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with UML representation, then use

Press `⌥⇧⌘U` or `⌥⌘U` on mac

Press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+U` or `Ctrl+Alt+U` on default windows keymap

See  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/viewing-class-hierarchy-as-a-class-diagram.html

Comment: I seem to not have this option somehow. I have an IDEA v2016.2.5, but this functionality should already be there: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/viewing-class-hierarchy-as-a-class-diagram.html. However, the shortcuts do not work (I am on Linux) and I do not see that option in the context menu. If it's not caused by some plugin missing, I guess it's because this project is in fact a mix of Java and Groovy, which might not be supported by the diagramming functionality.