# How to identify all classes implementing a specific interface that do NOT extend some base class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some interface `Action`, and most of the classes implementing that interface are derived from some base `AbstractAction`. But I assume there are some classes that implement that interface, but that do not extend that base class.

Is there a way using IntelliJ to identify such classes? (ideally: using the community edition)

Edit: this is not a duplicate of [How to show all parents and subclasses of a class in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990781/how-to-show-all-parents-and-subclasses-of-a-class-in-intellij-idea), as I am looking to combine a condition like "implements X and NOT extends Y".

Comment: Sir, I do not think this option is available in Intellij community edition, I don't know about ultimate edition.

Comment: Any comments by the downvoters?

Comment: I think no IDE like Eclipse and Idea provides this feature. I think this kind of feature should be added to the IDEs for more analysis.

Comment: Can I ask what your use case is? Maybe you can use a checkstyle configuration to warn if a class implements X and does not extend Y?

Comment: @sfiss I want to add a custom toString() method to all Actions. I will put it in the base class, but for sure, it also needs to go into any other class implementing the interface but not inheriting from the base class.

Comment: BTW: there is this incredibly powerful Live Plugin https://github.com/dkandalov/live-plugin which can pimp IDEA e.g. in a way to write the lookups in Groovy and use the Find tool window to Display the results. So only the sky is the limit in finding stuff ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works only in **Intellij IDEA Ultimate Edition**:
The only thing that comes into my mind to sort of solve your problem directly with Intellij IDEA  is to generate the [uml class diagramm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html) of your `Action` interface.

This lets you search visually for hierarchy patterns.

Here is a diagramm for the `JTextComponent` as an example:

[image]

**Another approach - Using the right tool for the job**

[jqassistant](https://jqassistant.org/get-started/) is a tool that analyses your java code and its relations and stores that into a neo4j database. 
This enables you to describe your problem as graph query with [cypher](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher-query-language/).

The easiest way to get started is to

- download the binary distribution
  [jqassistant](https://jqassistant.org/get-started/)
- run `./bin/jqassistant.sh scan -f your_application.jar`, then
- start the server via `./bin/jqassistant.sh server`
- and open http://localhost:7474/browser/

  - alternatively use the  [Intellij plugin for jqassistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7618-jqassistant-plugin/versions)

Example:
The query for finding all classes implementing `aInteface` would look like

```
MATCH (i:Interface {name:"aIntefaces"}  )<-[:IMPLEMENTS]- (c) RETURN i,c
```

A query to your problem would look like:

```
MATCH 
   (i:Interface {name:'Action'}  )<-[:IMPLEMENTS|EXTENDS*1..10]- (class), 
   (abstractAction:Class {name:'AbstractAction'}) 
   where not (class)-->(abstractAction)   
RETURN class
```

Comment: JetBrains support told me to look into "structural search/replace", but for now, I like the idea of using jQasssistant.

Comment: In case you want to earn another accept today ... maybe checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667478/how-to-include-package-into-query ;-)