# How to include package into query?

Tags: java, jqassistant

This question is a continuation of [How to identify all classes implementing a specific interface that do NOT extend some base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664166/how-to-identify-all-classes-implementing-a-specific-interface-that-do-not-extend).

The accepted answer there suggests to use:

```
MATCH 
   (i:Interface {name:'Action'}  )<-[:IMPLEMENTS|EXTENDS*1..10]- (class), 
   (abstractAction:Class {name:'AbstractAction'}) 
   where not (class)-->(abstractAction)   
RETURN class
```

That works nicely, and gives a list of classes matching that condition.

The only problem I have: the name of that interface `Action` is (surprise) ambiguous. The absolute class name `com.whatever.foo.bar.Action` would be. But when I change the query to use `{name:'com.whatever.foo.bar.Action'}` I get an empty result.

I then tried `{package:'com.whatever.foo.bar' name:'Action'}`, but that doesn't work:

> One of the property names in your query is not available in the database, make sure you didn't misspell it or that the label is available when you run this statement in your application (the missing property name is: **package**)

Is there a way reduce the search result to *that* Action interface I really care about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `fqn` node property - full qualified name.

So the correct query would be:

```
MATCH 
   (i:Interface {fqn:'com.whatever.foo.bar.Action'}  )<-[:IMPLEMENTS|EXTENDS*1..10]- (class), 
   (abstractAction:Class {fqn:'com.whatever.foo.bar.AbstractAction'}) 
   where not (class)-->(abstractAction)   
RETURN class
```

This query produces a cartesian produckt which means that it's not very performant.

The following image shows the execution plan of that query for one of my projects:
[image]

This questions deals with that problem in more detail: [Why does neo4j warn: "This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352673/why-does-neo4j-warn-this-query-builds-a-cartesian-product-between-disconnected)

Since this query is just for analysis purposes and not executed against a production system, I would ignore that hint.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to find all classes implementing `com.whatever.foo.bar.Action` which do not extend `com.whatever.foo.bar.AbstractAction` your query should look like this:

```
MATCH 
  (class:Type:Class)-[:EXTENDS|IMPLEMENTS*]->(:Type:Interface{fqn:"com.whatever.foo.bar.Action"})
WHERE NOT
  (class)-[:EXTENDS*]->(:Type:Class{fqn:"com.whatever.foo.bar.AbstractAction"})
RETURN
  class
```

(IMHO this is quite self-expressive)

Two hints:

- Looking up Java types should always be done using the indexed fqn property of the `Type` label which takes the fully qualified class name
- You should always qualify the relationships, i.e. instead of `(class)-->(abstractAction)` use `(class)-[:EXTENDS*]->(abstractAction)` as beside EXTENDS or IMPLEMENTS there might be many outgoing relationships of a class node (e.g. DEPENDS_ON, ANNOTATED_BY) which all would be traversed by a query

Comment: I will have a look later this week!

Answer (score 1):

A closer look at the result graph of the "working" query revealed the simple answer, as one can simply use the `fileName` property:

```
MATCH 
 (i:Interface {name:"Action", fileName:"/com/whatever/foo/bar/Action.class"}  )<-[:IMPLEMENTS]- (c) 
RETURN c
```